# Correct Table Structure for One-To-Many

Tags: java, database, one-to-many

I have a User class with 3 lists of another classes. how to structure table in oracle db in correct way? I can't use any ORM like hibernate, must I use reference table or there are some ways do it with foreign keys? example class:

```
public class User {

    private List<Address> addresses;
    private List<Car> cars;
    private List<Company> companies;

//setters & getters
}
```

Comment: Do you have any table structure created already? Can you provide it?
Also given this class it should be only necessary to add user_id column in all these 3 tables(address, car, company) and mark it as foreign key.

Comment: If your database design is ready then you can use **Reverse engineer from JDBC Connection** to generate pojo's. [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)